diffing jupyter notebooks (nbdime), granular output diff
I used nbdime (directly, calling diff python methods), to diff a notebook used as a test.
It works well, except if a cell's output is large, the diff includes all the output from the cell in a diff, not just the lines where the output is different.
Say if I have a cell:
import random
i = random.randomint(0,99)
for j in range(100):
   print(f"{j} {j==i}")

This will output 100 lines, where on each run exactly one will be different.
nbdime for this cell would always include all 100 lines, where I'd just care for the two (one in original run, one in new run) that are different.
Is there any way to do this? (again, note that I'm calling python code directly, i.e. diff_notebooks(nb1, nb2) from the notebooks package, and pretty_print_notebook_diff from prettyprint package.
